# Music player with Seekbar (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

- I was working in a very simple music player with a seek bar. But I got a problem with playing music,it doesn't work correctly every second - it backwards a while, then remain again like it's a buggy.

  I know why but I can't solve it.

  When the progress bar moves forward, the music recalibrates and vice versa, when the music moves forward, the progress bar recalibrates.
  It's probably because of that that every time it goes back.
  But I tried several things and still have the same problem.
- Another problem is that when the music is paused, the progress bar goes in the opposite direction until it reaches zero. It doesn't stay where it was before the break.

**The full code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private boolean bool = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sound_bar);
    this.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.music);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() * seekBar.getMax() / mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        }
    }, 500, 500);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress() * mediaPlayer.getDuration() / seekBar.getMax());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}

public void playSound(View view) {

    Button button = (Button) view;

    if(bool) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        bool = false;
        button.setText("Jouer le son");
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        bool = true;
        button.setText("Mettre en pause");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(bool) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use another thread to control the seekbar would help.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16149722/6549174)